# Secure Cookie on HTTP site

Tags: web-application, cookies

I was asked this question "If the cookie is marked secure and the web application is over http , Cannot we access the application ?"

Considering the secure flag is to ensure the cookie is sent only on encrypted network

Comment: How can the application even work if it uses a cookie with flag secure but does not use HTTPS? In case of plain HTTP no cookie will be sent and thus the application not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Secure-only` means that the cookie won't be sent to a server using insecure (http) connection. So the application cannot rely on it from a server side.

Cookie could still be sued by client side code (ie: javascript) so long `Http only` is not set (probably a bad idea tho).

Note that according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies

> Starting with Chrome 52 and Firefox 52, insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the Secure directive.

So your http application wouldn't even be able to set the cookie (browser won't save it, or maybe will save it but without the `secure` flag: in such case, the application might "still work" since it will receive the cookie on next `http` request)

Last, you could still "access" the application, but you will be seen as "anonymous" since no cookie will be sent.